# How can pick up a particular months date from a list of array contains dates

Tags: node.js, reactjs, momentjs

```
let date_obj =  [ '2023-01-25',
     '2023-01-26',
     '2023-01-31',
     '2023-02-01',
     '2023-02-02',
     '2023-02-07',
     '2023-02-08',
     '2023-02-09',
     '2023-02-14',
     '2023-02-15',
     '2023-02-16',
     '2023-02-21',
     '2023-02-22',
     '2023-02-23',
     '2023-02-28' ],
```

lets say I need the dates which are from the month 01

the output should be like: `['2023-01-25','2023-01-26','2023-01-31']`

How can I get that I am using moment and nodejs.

Comment: if you want to use moment you can filter with this: `const filtered_jan = date_obj.filter(date => moment(date).month() === 0);`. The months start from 0 to 11 January is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filter method to get result.

```
let date_obj =  [ '2023-01-25', '2023-01-26', '2023-01-31', '2023-02-01', '2023-02-02', '2023-02-07', '2023-02-08', '2023-02-09', '2023-02-14', '2023-02-15', '2023-02-16', '2023-02-21', '2023-02-22', '2023-02-23', '2023-02-28' ]
let date_obj_jan = date_obj.filter(date => date.indexOf('-01-') == 4);
console.log(date_obj_jan);
```